# How to check new project into svn?

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a new project which I'd like to check into my remote repository: `http://12.41.41.44/svn`

I just want the basic flow from command line:

- Check new project into remote SVN
- add any changes I make
- commit those changes to remote SVN

In my new project (which doesn't have `.svn` yet) I get this error when I do `svn add`

```
svn: E155007: '/my/folder/projfolder' is not a working copy
```

How can I do the three items listed above from command line on a new local folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **projects** folder with a folder **my_project**

First of all, import your code to your svn server.

```
cd projects
svn import my_project http://12.41.41.44/svn
```

When your import is finished get the code (checkout) from the svn in another folder.

```
mkdir my_sync_project
cd my_sync_project
svn co http://12.41.41.44/svn .
```

Now your project is synchronized with the svn.

```
cd my_sync_project
```

Create a new file

```
echo 'Hello world!' >> hello.txt
```

Check the status of your code

```
svn st
```

Add the file and send it (commit) to your svn

```
svn add hello.txt
svn ci -m 'Commiting the hello.txt file to my svn'
```

Comment: Thanks! in this case you knew which foe to add so you did `svn add hello.txt` but what if I had multiple files that needed to be added.

Comment: Try this solution:

    svn st | grep "^?" | awk '{ print $2}' | while read f; do svn add "$f"; done

http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/how-to-add-multiple-files-to-subversion.html

Answer (score 0):

If using windows I suggest using tortoisesvn and if using linux rabitvcs. Much easier than any command line.

Comment: yes, for tortoisesvn see [link](http://awgtek.blogspot.com/2009/03/tortoisesvn-quick-start_22.html)